# Log all items of checked checkboxes to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, console.log

I have three checkboxes which have a class name of (names). I am trying to say if the checkbox is checked log the value to the console.

```
if( $('.names').is(':checked') ){
        console.log($('.names').val()); 
    }else{
        console.log('null'); 
    }
```

However, this is only logging the first value to the console (when there is more than one ticked).

Do i need to create an array and log that?

Comment: `$('.names:checked').each(function() { console.log($(this).val()); });`

Answer (score 2):

The getter version of `val()` will return the value of the first element only.

One solution is to get an array of all the checked values and print it

```js
var checked = $('.names:checked').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
if (checked.length) {
  console.log(checked);
} else {
  console.log('null');
}
```

Comment: `Do i need to create an array and log that?` doesn't mean OP _want_ array.

Comment: `if (checked.length) {
  console.log(checked);
} else {
  console.log('null');
}` not required ==> only `console.log(checked);` will do

Answer (score 1):

While you have a correct answer posted already, it's worth noting that jQuery is not required for this to be 'easy'; it's quite possible in vanilla JavaScript:

```js
// creating a named function to handle the change-event (later):
function logToConsole() {
  // retrieves a collection of elements that match the CSS selector:
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].names:checked'),
    // converts the collection to an Array:
    values = Array.prototype.slice.call(checked, 0)

    // map iterates over the Array returned by
    // Array.prototype.slice():
    .map(function(checkbox) {
    // checkbox is the Array Element itself:

      // returning the value of the checked checkbox:
      return checkbox.value;
    });

  // if the collection has a length other than 0:
  if (checked.length) {

    // outputs the array of values to the console:
    console.log(values);
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('change', logToConsole);
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Check any of the check-boxes to see the values of those check-boxes logged to the console</legend>
    <label>value: 3
      <input value="3" class="names" type="checkbox" />
    </label>
    <label>value: 4
      <input value="4" class="names" type="checkbox" />
    </label>
    <label>value: 5
      <input value="5" class="names" type="checkbox" />
    </label>
    <label>value: 6
      <input value="6" class="names" type="checkbox" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: _I am trying to say if the checkbox is checked log the value to the console._, not Number of checked checkboxes

Comment: @Tushar: yes, I hadn't seen your comment but I have updated my answer as you were commenting to do that; I realised for myself once I'd posted.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript solution:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.names:checked'), function (cb) {
    console.log(cb.value);
});
```

And if you wan't that for older browsers as well:

```
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('.names:checked');
for(var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++)
    console.log(cbs[i].value);
```